# How to disable download pop up in browser from c# .Net

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have added pdf download to my application. When i click on download, browser is asking for whether to save or open the pdf document. But i need to set open as default so that it will not prompt for next time.

Here is my code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + "Report.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(pdfFileName);
```

Comment: That code will work, unless you have a security setting in your browser which demands user confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will help u.
Convert the attach file into buffer firstly..

```
        Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);

        if (buffer != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        }
```

Comment: It is working fine now. I need to set default zoom size of adobe reader to 100%. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't control that, it's in the scope of your clients browser to deal with that.